# Как привести определенные элементы строки в верхний регистр?

Tags: python, строки

Нужно взять в строке каждый второй символ и привести его в верхний регистр.

Пример:
Ввод: `future`
Вывод: `FuTuRe`

Вот так получаю и вывожу каждый второй символ:

```
a = 'future'
b = a[::2]
print(b)
```

Как вместе с ними выводить остальные символы?

Comment: Какие ваши мысли на эту тему

Comment: Создайте пустую строку. В цикле начните перебирать введённое слово и побуквенно добавлять к пустой строке символы. Метод перевода символа в верхний регистр — `upper`.

Comment: Вы можете через срезы не только читать данные, но и присваивать. Но только не в строку. Нужно будет перевести строку в список, и тогда вы можете прямо в срез присвоить обратно данные, предварительно их преобразовав в верхний регистр. И потом обратно сделать из списка строку. А вообще у этой задачи много возможных решений.

Comment: `print(''.join([ v if i%2 else v.upper() for i, v in enumerate('future')]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
a = 'future'

result = ''
for i, s in enumerate(a):
    if i % 2 == 0:           # Если индекс чётный
        result += s.upper()  # Добавить символ в верхнем регистре
    else:
        result += s

print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
FuTuRe
```

Answer (score 7):

Еще один короткий вариант решения:

```
"".join([x.upper() + y for x,y in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])])
>>> 'FuTuRe'
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно и короче, при использовании тернарного выражения и генератора. Пример ниже

```
>>> string = 'future'
>>> result = ''.join(x.lower() if i%2 else x.upper() for i, x in enumerate(string))
>>> result
FuTuRe
```